# how to fix the position of scrollbar of scrolledtext widget in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

i want to fix the postion of scrollbar of scrolledtext widget of tkinter.
i'am creating a chatbot where after every new message there is need to drag the scrollbar down to see conversation which has a bad impact.
here is the code of scrolledtext

```
        self.conversation = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(self,
                                                      state='disabled',borderwidth=5,
                                                      highlightthickness=1,
                                                      bg='#15202b',fg='#16202A',
                                                      font=('Arial Bold',8))

        self.conversation.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky='nesw', padx=3, pady=3)
```

Comment: post working example that will reproduce the problem

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the text widget? There are documented methods for scrolling and moving items into view.

Comment: it works fine but problem is that every time require to drag the scrollbar down to see new message and i want to fix the position of scrollbar of **ScrolledText**

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext


root = Tk()


scroll_x = Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal")
text = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, wrap=NONE)

text.config(xscrollcommand=scroll_x.set)
scroll_x.configure(command=text.xview)

text.pack(fill=X)
scroll_x.pack(fill=X)

for i in range(10000):
    text.insert(END, str(i)+"\n")
    text.see("end")
    root.update()

root.mainloop()
```

The command you are looking for is see("end")

```
text.see("end")
root.update()
```